# Angular material 14 to 15: <span class="spacer"></span> no longer works in a <mat-list-item>. Works in 14

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

In Angular 14 this html

```
    <mat-nav-list class="programs">
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let dataObject of filteredPrograms" (click)="selectProgram(dataObject)">
            {{dataObject.programName}}
            <span class="spacer"></span>
            <button mat-icon-button (click)="deleteProgram(dataObject); $event.stopPropagation()">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
```

works fine. It puts a left-justified name and right-justified button on the row. In other words, the `<span class="spacer"></span>` works.

When I move to Angular 15, the name is followed by the button; the `<span class="spacer"></span>` is ignored or is somehow changed and I can't find it's replacement. How can I get that spacing back?

Answer (score 0):

From another SO post I got this example for Angular 15 for a related issue:

```
<mat-list>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let position of cart">
    <h3 matListItemTitle> {{ position.name }} </h3>
    <p matListItemLine>Line 1</p>
    <button matListItemMeta mat-icon-button (click)="remove(1)">
      <mat-icon class="mat-24">delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

and it turned out all I needed to do was add the `matListItemMeta` to the button. Don't need the span at all. So the working example looks like this:

```
    <mat-nav-list class="programs">
        <mat-list-item *ngFor="let dataObject of filteredPrograms" (click)="selectProgram(dataObject)">
          {{dataObject.programName}}
            <button matListItemMeta mat-icon-button (click)="deleteProgram(dataObject); $event.stopPropagation()">
                <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-list-item>
    </mat-nav-list>
```

I have a feeling that the fact the `<span class="spacer"></span>` worked at all was a bug, though it worked from Angular 1 to 14 over a period of more than 4 years. The working example above should probably contain the matListItemTitle as either
`<hx matListItemTitle> {{ dataObject.programName }} </hx>`
or'
`<span matListItemTitle> {{ dataObject.programName }} </span>`

Both worked though it is not needed.